# Event retry mechanism in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm reading multiple topics from Kafka, then doing state operations, then saving to the Kafka again. Here is the flow;

```
val stream1 = topic1.map(prepareData())
val stream2 = topic2.map(prepareData1())
val delayStream = delayqueue.map(prepareData2()) // these messages comes from delay

val enrichedResults = stream1.union(stream2).union(delayStream).map(stateOperation)
val taggedStream = enrichedResults.process(tagStreamAsRetryOrNot)
val retryMessages = taggedStream.getSideOutput(tag)

retryMessages.addSink(kafkaDelayQueue1)
taggedStream.addSink(targetTopic)
```

In this flow, if any state can not be found, this message will be sent to the `delay queue`. I'll process this message later.

Other side of the delay flow:

`delayQueue(written by flink) => consumerAPP(check retrycounts and timestamps) => anotherQueue`

(This will be consumed by flink again. I do not want to send message to main topic again, because main topic is consumed by also another teams.)

Is this approach good? Can this flow be improved with less effort? Or Is there any best practices for that?

Comment: Why is the reprocessing/retrying necessary? Perhaps this be avoided by doing some sort of temporal join between the two streams.

Comment: I enrich topic2 messages using the sate saved from topic1 messages. Messages comes from topic2 may be come earlier than topic1. Thus, I have to re-process topic2 event that does not have a state.

Answer (score 3):

The way this is usually handled is to buffer the early messages in state until the expected messages carrying the data needed for enrichment arrive on the other stream. You can do this in a `KeyedCoProcessFunction`, for example.

Flink SQL (and the Table API) are set up to make doing this sort of streaming join easy.

See [the documentation on SQL joins](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sql/queries.html#joins) for more info on that topic.